# How do I consume this JSON in handlebars (or ordinary JS)?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

this is my JSON output (see below).

I need to consume it using handlebars so I can turn it into HTML. "insects" and "birds" are just placeholders. it can be anything.

```
{
    "insects":
        [
            {"name":"wasp"}
            ,{"name":"spider"}
        ]
    , "birds":
        [
            {"name":"eagle"}
            ,{"name":"pigeon"}
        ]
}
```

This is the desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over the keys of an object.

Example:

```js
const input = {
    "insects":
        [
            {"name":"wasp"}
            ,{"name":"spider"}
        ],
    "birds":
        [
            {"name":"eagle"}
            ,{"name":"pigeon"}
        ]
};

const categories = Object.keys(input); // categories now contains ["insect", "birds"]
```

Now you can iterate over the categories to do whatever you want to do with them.